# Каким образом к выводу файла подключить другой файл?

Tags: php

Делаю небольшой поиск по файлам ищу например головная боль мне находит и нужно подгрузить вопрос ответ из папки соответственного файла. фалы есть именами 1,   2. 3.
чтоб обяснить
открываю файл clinic.dat все стандартно

```
файл типа
1<|>головная боль, простата<|>вопрос<|>ответ<|>
2<|>киста, простата<|>вопрос<|>ответ<|>
3<|>вагинит, киста, простата<|>вопрос<|>ответ<|>

<code lang="php">
foreach ($file as $line) {
        $elem = explode('<|>', $line);

    echo $elem[0].$elem[1]. $elem[2]. $elem[3];

     //echo $matches[1].'-'.$matches2[1].'-'.$matches3[1];

//как подгрузить $elem[2]  =  .$matches2[1]  иии $elem[3 = $matches3[1]
  }

есть папка с файлами именами 1, 2, 3 и тд файлы с одерижимым

$articles = glob("./clinic/*");

    foreach($articles as $article)
    {
    
        $content = file_get_contents($article);

        preg_match("|\/clinic\/(.*).php|Ui", $article, $matches);

        preg_match("|question = <<< EOT(.*?)EOT;|is", $content, $matches2);

        preg_match("|response = <<< EOT(.*?)EOT;|is", $content, $matches3);
        
          echo $matches[1].'-'.$matches2[1].'-'.$matches3[1];

   }
```

Comment: Перечитал несколько раз - всё равно ничего не понял

Comment: Что значит "подключать другой файл с содержимым" ? Покажите имя другого файла и содержимое. А лучше распишите словами все действия, аля "открываем файл rond.dat, берём первую строку, разделяем её по <|> и..." и дальше что  сделать надо? Не понятно, дополните.

Comment: поправил вопрос